# How to sync image plane with camera movement?

Tags: camera, video, tracking

I did a footage with a crane in front of a green screen, where the camera points vertically down to the actor lying on the floor. He then stands up, while the camera goes back, while rotating 90 degrees.

Now what is the easiest possibility to synchronize the background with the camera movement.
Is it right, that - since the video footage is a 2D image plane - I need to place the image plane on the floor of the blender environment and make it rotate 90 degrees with the camera movement? Thanks for you support!